# Add Mathematical Equation in Protege

Tags: ontology, protege, mathematical-expressions

I want to develop an ontology using protege 5.0. In my ontology there is a data property named "x" which range is integer. Also I have a object property named "y". Is there anyway to add an equation like this to "y": x = x + 5. I want if the y happens adds 5 to x value. can I do this in protege?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do something like this with class and property axioms alone, but you can do it with a SWRL rule.  In particular, you'd do something like

> x(?i,?n) ∧ add(?n,5,?m) → y(?i,?m)

This says that when a (named) individual ?i has an x value of ?n, then it also has a y value of ?m, where ?m is equal to ?n + 5. The answers to some other questions can help you getting set up with SWRL rules in Protégé:

- [Ontology property definition in Protégé-OWL / SWRL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21499126/1281433)
- [SWRL rules in protege 3.4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21243879/1281433)
- [SWRL rules don't infer new Object and Data Property Assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21540839/1281433)