# How to execute SWRL Rules in Protege 4.3?

Tags: protege, swrl

I have created an ontology in Protege 4.3 along with a set of SWRL rules. In order to execute those rules and execute queries do I need another program to work with Protege or a plugin? Is a reasoner useful for this job? Searching I came across a lot of reasoners but I can't understand their usage, although I believe they may be relevant. I have found a lot of questions in here regarding Protege but none of them actually helped.

Comment: @JimL. That was the first thing that I did, it was necessary after all. What is the problem with my question?

Comment: How is the title a question?

Comment: @JimL. Do you mention this to all of the users? As I see the front page rarely features questions in titles.

Comment: Are you suggesting that linked page needs to change?

Comment: @JimL. No but this is merely a suggestion as you can see in the front page. Let's not consume our time with the title...The point is in the questions in the main body.

Comment: In what vocabulary are these rules expressed?

Comment: @JimL. They are expressed in SWRL if that is what you mean.

Comment: Have you tried the obvious [SWRLJess Tab](http://protege.cim3.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?SWRLJessTab) or [SWRLTab](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/SWRLTab")?

Comment: @Mandy if you're running a reasoner that supports SWRL rules (e.g., Pellet), then your rules will be used when the reasoner answers queries.  What queries are you running where you didn't get the results you expected? I agree with Jim L a bit, it's not really clear what the question here is. Is there something that's not working?

Comment: There are other questions that have examples of swrl rules in protégé here on stack overflow.  E.g.,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499126/ontology-property-definition-in-protégé-owl-swrl or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243879/swrl-rules-in-protege-3-4-8 .

Comment: Have you read The [OWL 2 and SWRL Tutorial](http://dior.ics.muni.cz/~makub/owl/)?

Comment: @JimL. Those two tabs are available only in Protege 3 and not 4. Do I need Java as in the tutorial to run the rules?

Comment: Before proceeding here, was Ignazio's answer helpful? If so, please up vote and accept his answer to give him and you reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

SWRL rules require a reasoner that supports them (as mentioned already by Joshua Taylor). This reasoner must come in the form of a Protege plugin to be usable inside Protege.

Usually Protege ships with at least one reasoner supporting SWRL rules, that's HermiT. You should see it available in the Reasoner menu.

To let any reasoner be used (for either SWRL or OWL inference), just select it and click on `Reasoner` -> `Start reasoner`.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded Pellet and I executed it but there is no effect. I found a plugin named Axiome for Protege 3 that processes the rules in graphs but it doesn't work in 4. Is something similar for 4? Or something else relevant?

Comment: "No effect" does not provide enough information to solve the problem. Do you get errors? Are your rules verified to work outside protégé?

Comment: By no effect I mean that it doesn't do absolutely anything without any errors showing somewhere. Furthermore I have checked that the rules are correct. Also I was told reasoners just check the validity of the rules and if I want to "process" them I need to use Java. Is this the case?

Comment: No - reasoners supporting rules include them seamlessly in the processing of the ontology.